# Sigabrt when trying to display another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, button, viewcontroller

I want to go to another view controller when pressing button my btnSignUp, If I write code like this I have error "sigabrt". What I should do?

```
import UIKit
import SnapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 15/255, green: 52/255, blue: 100/255, alpha: 1)

        createTop()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

 super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

    func createTop() {

        let topView = UIView()

        self.view.addSubview(topView)

        topView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 15/255, green: 52/255, blue: 100/255, alpha: 1)

        topView.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in

            make.width.equalTo((self.view.frame.width/10)*8)
make.height.equalTo(self.view.frame.height/5)

            make.centerX.equalTo(self.view)

            make.top.equalTo(self.view).offset(self.view.frame.height/15)
        }



        let btnSignUp = UIButton()

        self.view.addSubview(btnSignUp)

        btnSignUp.backgroundColor =  UIColor(red: 15/255, green: 52/255, blue: 100/255, alpha: 1)

        btnSignUp.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor

        btnSignUp.layer.borderWidth = 1

        btnSignUp.layer.cornerRadius = 6

        btnSignUp.setTitle("Sign Up", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        btnSignUp.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 17)

        btnSignUp.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in

 make.width.equalTo(((self.view.frame.width/10)*7)+40)

            make.height.equalTo(self.view.frame.height/13)

            make.top.equalTo(ORView.snp_bottom).offset(20)

            make.centerX.equalTo(self.view)
        }

        btnSignUp.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

  func buttonAction(sender:UIButton!)
        {

            let signUpVC = SignUpViewController()

            self.presentViewController(signUpVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: are you using xib or storyboard ?

Comment: Snap Kit, not storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Your action selector `buttonAction` doesn't match your function declaration - It takes an argument, so the selector will be `buttonAction:`

```
btnSignUp.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

Additionally, check your parentheses.  It appears that your `buttonAction` function is declared *inside* `func createTop()`

```
func createTop() {

    let topView = UIView()

    self.view.addSubview(topView)

    topView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 15/255, green: 52/255, blue: 100/255, alpha: 1)

    topView.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in

        make.width.equalTo((self.view.frame.width/10)*8)
make.height.equalTo(self.view.frame.height/5)

        make.centerX.equalTo(self.view)

        make.top.equalTo(self.view).offset(self.view.frame.height/15)
    }

    let btnSignUp = UIButton()

    self.view.addSubview(btnSignUp)

    btnSignUp.backgroundColor =  UIColor(red: 15/255, green: 52/255, blue: 100/255, alpha: 1)

    btnSignUp.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor

    btnSignUp.layer.borderWidth = 1

    btnSignUp.layer.cornerRadius = 6

    btnSignUp.setTitle("Sign Up", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    btnSignUp.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 17)

    btnSignUp.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in

         make.width.equalTo(((self.view.frame.width/10)*7)+40)
         make.height.equalTo(self.view.frame.height/13)
         make.top.equalTo(ORView.snp_bottom).offset(20)
         make.centerX.equalTo(self.view)
    }

    btnSignUp.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
}

func buttonAction(sender:UIButton!) {

    let signUpVC = SignUpViewController()
    self.presentViewController(signUpVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Finally, I doubt that you want to get your new view controller by `SignUpViewController()` - if you are using a storyboard you want to call `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`

Comment: I have thread 1: signal SIGABRT error, how to solve this problem, help me pls, I spend two days to solve this

Comment: sigabrt is comes in many scenarios , enable zombies and check

Comment: class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {